# Spring Integration Sftp Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter processing same file multiple times

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am  using spring integration sftp inbound streaming channel adapter which polls every few seconds. The inbound adapter is picking the same file for processing multiple times. Below is the configuration.

```
<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
        channel="ftpChannel"
        session-factory="sessionFactory"
        filter="filter"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        remote-directory="/sampleFolder" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="30000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>



<int:stream-transformer id="withCharset" charset="UTF-8"
input-channel="ftpChannel" output-channel="outputChannel"/> 

<bean id="filter"
class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean
            class="sample.CustomFilter">

</bean>
         <bean
class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters. 
AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

sample.CustomFilter in the above code is a subclass of  SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter where I had the accept method modified as below to accept only the file having current date in its name as per the solution present in [Spring SFTP varying filename-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903674/spring-sftp-varying-filename-regex)

```
public boolean accept(ChannelSftp.LsEntry file){
setPattern(new java.text.SimpleFormat("yyyyMMDD").format(new 
java.util.Date())+".txt$"
super.accept(file);
}
```

The issue being faced is the same file being processed multiple files. the file is being retained in the same remote directory after processing.  Is there some issue with my filter configuration Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` is based on the object hash, meanwhile the `SftpStreamingMessageSource` produces an `LsEntry` where each new objected created, even  with the same file name has its own new hash.

What you need to make it working is with the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which already does what you would like to achieve.

In addition I would suggest to use a `ChainFileListFilter` instead of the `CompositeFileListFilter`. This way the file won't reach that `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` if it doesn't pass a `CustomFilter`. Therefore no extra memory consumption for files we are not interested in at all.

See more info in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading